# how to fix programmatic navigation issue using react and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-tsx

I'm new to react and I'm learning react programmatic navigation using typescript.since most of the tutorials are with java script, I'm not able to resolve issue with programmatic navigation using typescript

As in most of the tutorials i tried

```
this.props.history.push("/page");
```

which shows an error *'history' does not exist on type*

i tried several solutions like

```
 const history=createBrowserHistory();
 history.push("/page")
```

This method will change url path but component will not load as mentioned here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059

i also tried another solutions

```
this.context.push("/page");
```

which gives me below error
*TypeError: _this.context.push is not a function*

My full code

```
import * as queryString from 'query-string';
import * as React from 'react';



interface IrentalProps{
name:string,
}



class Rental extends React.Component<IrentalProps, any> {

public extracturl=()=>{

    const stringfy=queryString.parse(location.search);
    return stringfy.id;
}
public handleClick=()=>{
   this.context.push("/page"); //issue 
}
public render() { 
    return ( 
        <div style={{paddingTop:100}}>
        {this.extracturl()}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>navigate</button> //calling the function
       </div>
     );
}

}

export default Rental;
```

I only need to navigate to another page on a button click as in SPA using typescript and browserrouter

Note:redirect is working and hashrouter with createhashhistory()  is also working .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when creating your own history you need to use Router not BrowserRouter .

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const History = createBrowserHistory()
export default History;
```

and pass history to props of router

thanks to BTM

Answer (score 0):

you need the react-router types. at the root of the project install them (package.json)

`npm install --save @types/react-router`

and

`npm install --save @types/react-router-dom`

Comment: already have them in root .I'm not importing them here  since i'm not using any dependencies of these libraries